# How to pass a parameter to Rubix ML TextNormalizer->transform() method? Arguments cannot be passed by reference

Tags: laravel, reference

I've got the command below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Rubix\ML\Datasets\Labeled;
use Rubix\ML\Extractors\CSV;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\TextNormalizer;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\WordCountVectorizer;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\TfIdfTransformer;
use Rubix\ML\Persisters\Filesystem;
use Rubix\ML\Classifiers\KNearestNeighbors;
use Rubix\ML\CrossValidation\Reports\MulticlassBreakdown;
use Rubix\ML\CrossValidation\Reports\ConfusionMatrix;

use Log;
class PredictorCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:predictor';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $mlModel = new PredictorCommand();

        echo "Please enter your text: ";
        $inputText = readline();
        $prediction = $mlModel->predict($inputText);

        echo "Prediction: {$prediction}";
    }

    public function predict($inputText)
    {
        // Load the trained model
        $modelPath = '/var/www/gdpr/tests/model.rbx';
        $modelData = file_get_contents($modelPath);
        $estimator = unserialize($modelData);

        // Preprocess the input text
        $textNormalizer = new TextNormalizer();
        $wordCountVectorizer = new WordCountVectorizer(10000);
        $tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

        $text = $inputText;
        $text = $textNormalizer->transform([$text]);
        $text = $wordCountVectorizer->fit($text)->transform($text);
        $text = $tfIdfTransformer->fit($text)->transform($text);

        // Make a prediction
        $prediction = $estimator->predictSample($text[0]);

        return $prediction;
    }

}
```

When running it I'm getting the following error:

```
Please enter your text: sd

   Error 

  Rubix\ML\Transformers\TextNormalizer::transform(): Argument #1 ($samples) cannot be passed by reference

  at app/Console/Commands/PredictorCommand.php:63
     59▕         $wordCountVectorizer = new WordCountVectorizer(10000);
     60▕         $tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();
     61▕ 
     62▕         $text = $inputText;
  ➜  63▕         $text = $textNormalizer->transform([$text]);
     64▕         $text = $wordCountVectorizer->fit($text)->transform($text);
     65▕         $text = $tfIdfTransformer->fit($text)->transform($text);
     66▕ 
     67▕         // Make a prediction

  1   app/Console/Commands/PredictorCommand.php:45
      App\Console\Commands\PredictorCommand::predict()

      +13 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Why is it being passed by reference? I thought the Array assignment always involved value copying.

If I run the code below:

```
$text = [$inputText];
$text = $textNormalizer->transform($text);
```

The error I get then is:

```
Rubix\ML\Transformers\TextNormalizer::normalize(): Argument #1 ($sample) must be of type array, string given
```

If I do this instead:

```
 $text[] = [$inputText];
 $text = $textNormalizer->transform($text);
```

The call works, but `$text` is null, so I cannot perform the following action, which is `$wordCountVectorizer->fit($text)->transform($text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have not used this package (Rubix ML) before, nor am I active with machine learning, but the issues seem purely php related. Therefore this answer can help get the code running, but that doesn't mean it will provide the desired result.

I have looked at the [source code](https://github.com/RubixML/ML/blob/master/src/Transformers/TextNormalizer.php#L54-L71) of the `TextNormalizer`. The function you're calling requires an `array`, which calls another function, which should also be an `array`. The values are passed by reference, so you can't pass anything but a predefined variable in the method. This is why your last try (`$text[] = [$inputText]`) works because it creates the required structure. Also, the `transform` method returns `void`, so if you assign `$text` to the return type of `transform`, it will always be `null` due to the `void` return type.

The next part is the [`WordCountVectorizer`](https://github.com/RubixML/ML/blob/master/src/Transformers/WordCountVectorizer.php#L145-L241). The `fit` method expects a `Dataset` type. According to the [docs](https://docs.rubixml.com/2.0/basic-introduction.html#the-dataset-object), you can make datasets either labeled or unlabeled. For my example, I will use unlabeled datasets, but the desired dataset is up to you. The `transform` method expects an `array` like before.

Then the last call, the [`tfIdfTransformer`](https://github.com/RubixML/ML/blob/master/src/Transformers/TfIdfTransformer.php#L132-L203), works the same as the `WordCountVectorizer`. Therefore, we can do the following:

```php
$text = [[$inputText]];
// $text is a reference, so the original value is updated
$textNormalizer->transform($text);
// Create dataset with transformed text
$dataset = new \Rubix\ML\Datasets\Unlabeled($text);
// Again, $text is a reference
$wordCountVectorizer->fit($dataset);
$wordCountVectorizer->transform($text);
// Update dataset with transformed $text
$dataset = new \Rubix\ML\Datasets\Unlabeled($text);
// Again, $text is a reference
$tfIdfTransformer->fit($dataset);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($text);
```

Again, this should get your code up and running, but I cannot guarantee the result is as desired.

Comment: Thank you @Yinci, it makes total, sense, although the following line is still giving me an error:  $wordCountVectorizer->fit($dataset)->transform($text);
Returns: Call to a member function transform() on null

Comment: @InigoEC I have updated my code. Apparently, the developer has not introduced method chaining in his code (which I assumed there was, based on your code snippet). Now, the calls are on separate lines.